# cannot get hidden form field data

Tags: java, html, servlets

im trying to get the hidden value i saved in my jsp's table that i called noteid. im trying to use noteid in my controller but i cant get access to it, when i use int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noteid")); i get a null error 500. how can i get the data from the jsp hidden field to use in my controller?

this is my jsp that has the table of links of titles, unless ive misused the hidden form field to save the note id. it should be right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>MyNotes</title>
</head>
<body>

<p align="right">Hello, ${sessionScope.CurrentUser}!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Logout">Logout</a></p>
<span>JOT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="MyNotes">My Notes</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="NewNote.jsp">New</a></span>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<table border=1>

  <tr><th>Titles</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="NoteDetails?id="${entry.getId()}>${entry.title}</a></td>
     <td><input type="hidden"  value="${entry.getId()}" id="noteid" name="noteid"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>

<p><a href="NewNote.jsp">New Note</a></p>



</body>
</html>




here the controller for my notedetails.im trying to get the noteid i saved from the hidden form field in my jsp





@WebServlet("/Homework2/NoteDetails")
public class NoteDetails extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        getServletContext().setAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note", new ArrayList<Notes>());

        Notes note = null;
        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noteid"));
            ArrayList<Notes> entries = (ArrayList<Notes>) getServletContext().getAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note");
            for (Notes e : entries){
                if (e.getId() == id){
                    note = e;
                    System.out.println(e+"+"+id);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        finally{
            if (note == null){
                System.out.println("WRONG");
                return;
            }
        }






}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not submiting the hidden field via a form

Following is just an example

```
<form action="hello" >
<input type="hidden" value="100" name="id"/>
input type="submit"/>
```

servlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
int i=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
}
```

Comment: i just looked at my notes, im not supposed to use a hidden form field , how would i pass the <td><a href="NoteDetails?id="${entry.getId()}>${entry.title}</a></td> id into my controller?

Comment: @user3225981 simply use request.getParameter("id");

Answer (score 0):

i have  use the input type hidden in html

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test1"/>
</form>
```